# Error when trying to Deploy MonoTouch App to iPhone

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am trying to deploy my MonoTouch Application to my iPhone.  I have set up the profile on the phone and purchased the MonoTouch license.  However when I try to deploy to the iPhone I am getting the following error:

```
mtouch failed with no output(1)
```

The compiler is giving this error:

```
Error: You should provide one root assembly only.
```

This only appears when I try to deploy the application to the iPhone.  If I use the simulator it compiles and runs fine.

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

UPDATE:

Actually this error only occurs if I try to Debug on the iPhone.  If I use the Release build option it actually deploys fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs when more than one argument to 'mtouch' is not preceded by an option.

If you're using MonoDevelop then this could occur if you added some "Additional mtouch arguments" (in Options | iPhone Build). Since they could be different in Build and Debug it could explain why you have no issue in Release mode. Try matching the Debug arguments to the Release arguments.

If you're using mtouch on the command line then check every one of your arguments. Only one should not be prefixed, and this should be the name of your main assembly.

Comment: At one point I did try linking an external library but I gave up when I couldn't get it to work.  I thought I had removed the extra arguments for that but I'll go back and double check.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem.  I don't remember added that linking code to that build profile but it wasn't removed when I cleaned up the Debug | iPhoneSimulater profile.  Anyway it's all good now, thanks.